# Удаление веток реестра по условию через PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, реестр

Стоит задача скриптом удалить содержимое ветки реестра:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList**

Кроме первых четырех веток содержащихся внутри!
Подскажите каким образом обработать такое условие?

Comment: Какая сортировка, что такое первые? **Первые**: по имени, по дате создания, по дате модификации, по дате последней активности каталога профиля пользователя, относящегося к соответствующей ветви реестра?

Comment: Первые 4 папки в разделе, которые выглядят так: "S-1-5-18", "S-1-5-19", "S-1-5-20", "S-1-5-21". Остальные папки раздела - создаются динамически, их то и нужно удалять. Я вижу условие как "Удалить ВСЁ кроме этих 4х по имени", "Удалить ВСЁ кроме первых 4х после ". Вопрос как реализовать.

Comment: Просто два примера. Найти ветви реестра длиной равной 3 символам: **"Get-ChildItem -Path "HKCU:\dummy\*"|where { $_.pschildname.length -eq 3}"**. Команда чтобы удалить все вложенные ветви без запроса: **"Remove-Item -recurse"**.      P.S. Думаю без подсказки ясно, что SID встроенных У/З имеет конкретную длину.

Comment: Daemon-5 - спасибо за наводку, буду разбираться!